# How to connect with different computer to join the channel and view the invoke contents (transaction) in real time on hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, channel, peer

I am a student studying Hyperledger Fabric.
Is there a way to check the transaction history in the block created through the hyperledger fabric on another computer in real time?

I have built channels and peers.
How do I access two channels using two computers?

Many people speak SDK, Rest-API, BNA, etc., but it's conceptually difficult.
Should I use them all?

I just want to coding a simple code where 10 strings are entered and formed into one block.
Please help me.

```
ca.org1.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org1.example.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/fd6ad41bc5687605cf9c9c2e5e0b8913ea3e49975ab09e4fece68723e5fcecb8_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.org1.example.com
    extra_hosts:
      - "ca.org1.example.com:192.168.xxx.xxx"
      - "ca.org2.example.com:192.168.xxx.xxx"
      - "orderer.example.com:192.168.xxx.xxx"
      - "peer0.org1.example.com:192.168.xxx.xxx"
      - "peer1.org1.example.com:192.168.xxx.xxx"
      - "peer0.org2.example.com:192.168.xxx.xxx"
      - "peer1.org2.example.com:192.168.xxx.xxx"
```

my docker-compose-cli.yaml file.

I haven't studied long...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  What have your tried?  Have you gone through the tutorials?

Comment: Do you tried to configure Hyperledger Explorer? I fully recommend to use an SDK.

Comment: I have built a channel in blocks. And we set peer0 and 1. I want to set up peer1 as an external host and hope that pee1 gets the value properly when it sends a query. I want to configure an external host but I'm not sure how

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple nodes on different computers using the docker swarm.
Where the swarm will be maintained by orderer system 
you can create swarm network in this way 
`docker swarm init  --advertise-addr <orderer ip> #ip of your orderer`

Above command  will generate token like->

`docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-1v7iz94ay5ubv6tg93lh82q2s4yekcbndgldydcrtjz06tzv9j-22njpwu7igsfmpqc4zdbjybap 10.244.5.78:2377`

run the above token command  on the other computers to make them join the swarm  network.
Now you can see if they joined the network by `docker node ls`
This will list you all the workers and managers in the swarm network.

Now run this command in all nodes to see that they docker network also runs in swarm
`docker run -itd --name hello --net docker-config_default busybox #a docker-config_default n/w is created`

Then you can check with `docker network ls` if the network is created.
now you can stop and remove the container `docker stop hello &&
docker rm hello`
Before starting the docker containers be sure to add this in your all docker yaml files

```
version: '2'
networks:
      default:
        external:
                name: docker-config_default
```

Now by going in each system into the directory where you have the yaml files of the organization peers and orderer start them example 1) `docker-compose -f docker-orderer.yaml up -d`
2) In other systems`docker-compose -f docker-ca.yaml up -d &&
docker-compose -f docker-peer0.yaml up -d &&
docker-compose -f docker-peer1.yaml up -d`
Now your nodes will be up and running and you can check them with curl command if they are reachable `curl ipofnode:7051` it should return some msg like , check for all the nodes if they all are reachable.
With the above steps multinode setup of fabric is achieved using docker swarm.
Now your good to go with the setup and now you can install the chaincode and instantiate your chaincode and invoke it.